# Using __FILE__ and __LINE__ in a user-defined macro

Tags: c++, exception, macros

I have a macro declared as such:

```
#define Ex(a) { throw MyException((a), __LINE__, __FILE__); }
```

And i'm using it like this:

```
if (bad_things_happen) Ex(error_code)
```

Will these macros contain the line and file of the `#define` statement, or the `if` statement? If they contain the line and file of the `#define` statement, then my macro is essentially useless...

Comment: Why don't you just test it and find out

Comment: @aaronman Why don't you just test it and find out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it expands to the line number where you use it:

> `__LINE__` This macro expands to the current input line number, in the form of a decimal integer constant. While we call it a predefined macro, it's a pretty strange macro, since its “definition” changes with each new line of source code.

As for file:

> `__FILE__` This macro expands to the name of the current input file, in the form of a C string constant. This is the path by which the preprocessor opened the file, not the short name specified in ‘#include’ or as the input file name argument. For example, "/usr/local/include/myheader.h" is a possible expansion of this macro.

Comment: ... but in this case, what would "where you use it" mean?

Comment: @creXALBO It would expand to the current line, not where the macro was defined. A macro is simply text replacement.

Comment: creXALBO's question is quite valid ... that a macro is simply text replacement really doesn't help explain since, as the text says, `__LINE__` is a "pretty strange" macro that *isn't* simply text replacement since its value changes. You should clarify your answer to specify that `__LINE__` has the value of the source line where it is expanded, not where it textually occurs. (Your comment above is not part of the answer.)